# What case is assigned by *like*?

Tags: syntax, case

In this sentence "They agreed unanimously that John looked like an extremely happy man", what gives case to 'man'? Is it 'like'? I know the preposition can assign case and I think the adjacency requirement is violated in this sentence because of 'extremely happy', but it is a grammatical sentence.why?

Comment: *Man* is caseless.

Comment: @snailboat mmm ... In this case *man* is unmarked for case. It may be marked for genitive case.

Comment: What *adjacency requirement* do you have in mind here?

Comment: If English were still marked for case, 'man' would be in the nominative, since "look like" is a predicate.  A modifying phrase between the determiner and the noun does not affect the case of the noun; the adjectives in the phrase would typically be inflected to agree with the case of the noun.

Comment: "like", originally an adjective (The son is like his father), is seen today as a preposition and prepositions are followed by an object case and not by a subject case.

Answer (score 4):

Nouns in English are not marked for any case except the genitive. Only pronouns (and only some of them) are marked for a distinction between subject and object case.

If you recast this predicate with a pronoun you will find that the complement of *like*<sup>†</sup> is always cast in object case when the distinction is discernible:

> ... looked like **me**
>   ... looked like **him**
>   ... looked like **her**
>   ... looked like **us**
>   ... looked like **them**

ADDED:
tchrist points out that you may encounter constructions with a “genitive”:

> ... looked like {**mine / yours / his / hers / its / ours / theirs**}

These are all cases where the genitive pronoun has ‘fused’ with the head noun to which it stands as a determiner; note that in five of the seven this fusion is morphologically marked. Note that the example does not speak of a likeness to the possessor, but a likeness to the thing possessed. These pronouns are properly described as “genitive” only internally, with respect to their determinative function; exernally, with respect to their syntactic role in the utterance, they have the case of their deleted head, which is unmarked for the subject/object distinction.

---

<sup>†</sup> I'm not going to get involved in the question of whether *like* is a preposition taking an object or an adjective taking a complement.

Comment: Pronouns also have a genitive case: *looked like mine*.

Comment: @tchrist Thanks for the cogent observation; I have now addressed it.